# ios Replace subStrings with a pattern

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, substring

I have a very long string and it contains some information that I do not want. For example, it constantly has something like:

`"<span class=/"phrasedesc/">....some text......</span phrasedesc>"`,

and I would like to remove all the substrings begin with `"<span class=/"phrasedesc/">"` and ends with `"</span phrasedesc>"`, no matter what's between.

Any one can help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it worked for me. :)

SWIFT:

```
let re = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(.*)(《span class=\"phrasedesc\"》.*《\\/span phrasedesc》)(.*)", options: .AnchorsMatchLines)

let stringToMatch = "adfasdfasdf《span class=\"phrasedesc\"》ajshdfljkahsdkjf  《/span phrasedesc》asdfasdfasdfasdf"

let matches = re.matchesInString(stringToMatch, options: .WithTransparentBounds , range: NSRange(location: 0, length: stringToMatch.characters.count))

re.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(stringToMatch, options: .ReportCompletion, range: NSMakeRange(0, stringToMatch.characters.count), withTemplate: "$1$3")
```

OBJECTIVE - C:

```
    NSString *stringToBeTrimmed = @"adfasdfasdf《span class=\"phrasedesc\"》ajshdfljkahsdkjf  《/span phrasedesc》asdfasdfasdfasdf";

    NSString *pattern = @"(.*)(《span class=\"phrasedesc\"》.*《\\/span phrasedesc》)(.*)";

    NSRegularExpression *expression = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines error:nil];

    NSString * yourResultingString =  [expression stringByReplacingMatchesInString:stringToBeTrimmed options:NSMatchingReportCompletion range:NSMakeRange(0, stringToBeTrimmed.length) withTemplate:@"$1$3"];
```

Comment: can u write it in OC plz

Comment: this works only if the pattern occurs onces. If there are many occurences of this pattern, I would like to remove all of them, but this did work.

Comment: Dude you are doing something wrong, i have tested adding multiple strings. This is working.

Answer (score -1):

Consider using [`stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/):

**Swift:**

```
let originalString = "<span class=\"phrasedesc\">....some text......</span phrasedesc>"
let newString = originalString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<span class=\"phrasedesc\">", withString: "")
let newString = newString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("</span phrasedesc>", withString: "")
```

**Objective-C:**

```
NSString *originalString = @"<span class=\"phrasedesc\">....some text......</span phrasedesc>";
newString = [originalString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<span class=\"phrasedesc\">" withString:@""];
newString = [newString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</span phrasedesc>" withString:@""];
```

**The result will be `newString == "....some text......"`**

Comment: What I want is remove the whole substring including .....some text.....part